# Magento 2 render duplicated products in category page

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products, color-swatches

I want to show duplicate products on category page based on visual swatch attribute.

For example:

> an configurable product has color swatch with 3 colors

It must render it 3 times on category page `(can be in different order)` but on product page `(on those products)` it must open main configurable product with pre selected color swatch.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: This may be a solution you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956249/forward-to-configurable-product-when-opening-simple-product But its for M1.

Comment: @KingshukDeb Kinda. Still cant decided how to do it on template level or in collection level.

Answer (score 1):

1.Add preselected colour attribute

2.Create observer for saving configurable products and listen for save action. Then create addition configurable products with preselected value based on specific simple product.

3. Make the existing configurable product hidden.

4.In product list (with js on php) do swatch preselect based on preselected attribute.

After that You will have 3 different products on listing page with different preselected colour.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with the first part of the question.
One simple product can be part of as many configurable products as you want.
Let's say you have a product in 3 colors. This means you are going to have 3 simple products.
You can create 3 configurable products, that contain every of the 3 simple products.

I'm still thinking of the second part

Comment: Thanks for idea! For second part i have solved only url part. like url?color=Red. One thing is still an issue modify configurable product url on render.